# Trouble understanding C++14 Relaxed constexpr restrictions

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, constexpr

I've came across new C++14 signature for `std::max` function:

```
template< class T > 
const T& max( const T& a, const T& b ); // (C++11)

template< class T > 
constexpr const T& max( const T& a, const T& b );// (C++14)
```

I've read about *Relaxed constexpr restrictions* proposal for C++14 but I'm still don't understand why this function return value can be `constexpr`

Example:

```
std::vector<int> a, b;
//This does not compile but as my understadnding of `constexpr` this should
int array[std::max(a.size(), b.size()]; (1)
//This is trivial use that does compile
int array[std::max(1,2)]; (2)
```

When calling `std::max` in (1) `constexpr` is ignored ?

Comment: `constexpr` here does not mean the function return value is `constexpr`. It means the function is `constexpr`.  (Similar to how `static int x();` doesn't mean that `x` returns a static int).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The base issue isn't directly related to relaxed constexpr rules, a constexpr function is only a constant expression if the arguments are constant expressions. In your second case:

```
int array[std::max(1,2)];
```

this works because integer literals are indeed constant expressions.

C++11 was more specific in this case, the draft C++11 standard in section `5.19` *[expr.const]* lays out the cases where a sub-expression is not considered a constant expression and contains the following:

> an invocation of a constexpr function with arguments that, when
>   substituted by function invocation substitution (7.1.5), do not
>   produce a constant expression;

in C++14 this paragraph was removed and we have the following exception:

> an invocation of a function other than a constexpr constructor for a
>   literal class, a constexpr function, or an implicit invocation of a
>   trivial destructor (12.4) [ Note: Overload resolution (13.3) is
>   applied as usual —end note ];

and we have to use the rest of the rules with respect to the arguments(*sub-expressions*).

In the first case:

```
int array[std::max(a.size(), b.size()];
```

[std::vector::size](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/size) is not marked constexpr and so it falls under the above quoted exception.

Also note that in section `7.1.5` *[dcl.constexpr]* we have the following:

> A call to a constexpr function produces the same result as a call to
>   an equivalent non-constexpr function in all respects except that a
>   call to a constexpr function can appear in a constant expression.

Passing arguments to a constexpr function that are not constant expressions just means the expression is not available for uses in contexts that require a constant expression.

As dyp points out that `std::max` was not made constexpr in C++11 due <s>to various issues probably including committee being conservative and limited time, we can see some of the issues involved in [N3039](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3039.pdf).</s> it being forgotten see [N3856](http://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3856.pdf) which says:

> This short paper proposes to make the standard functions min and max
>   constexpr. They were top on the list of motivating cases for al-
>   lowing reference parameters for constexpr functions in C++11. They
>   were forgotten after the core language change was accepted

For reference we know that `1` and `2` are constant expression from section `5.19` which says:

> A literal constant expression is a prvalue core constant expression of literal type, but not pointer type. An
>   integral constant expression is a literal constant expression of integral or unscoped enumeration type. [...]

Comment: I thought if function declared as `constexpr` than it only can be invoked with values that can be computed during compile time otherwise it'll be compile time error...

Comment: @dyp you know I had found [lwg 2350](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3893.html#2350) but I was confused because it went from wp -> open and I could not figure out why